# How can I make a Windows 7 allow me to edit a data file?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, text-editing

I am running a Windows 7 operating system. I would like to edit a data file named "hosts" that is found in the following library:
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
The OS does not allow changes, and I do not know how to acquire administrator's power to be able to make the change. 
In addition, which program can edit such a file (a built-in text editor or an external one)?

Answer (score 4):

From the Start menu, search for *Command Prompt*.  Right-click on the Command Prompt application and choose *Run as Administrator*.

At the command prompt type:

```
notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

This will open notepad as an administrator which will let you edit and save the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Notepad as Administrator (Right click on the shortcut in your start menu and choose 'Run as Administrator'), then open the HOSTS file from within Notepad.